# Problema UPDATE e claúsula WHERE com duas condições

Tags: php, post, sql-update

Após muita pesquisa na internet sem conseguir uma solução, recorro aos "universitários" de plantão!
Tenho duas tabelas: contrato(chave primária) e contatos. Sendo a segunda vinculada a primeira. Listo os registros da primeira e seleciono alterar em um registro. Para cada Contrato posso ter vários contatos.

O CRUD da tabela contrato está OK. O problema está na tabela contato. Criei uma pagina com iframe, para exibir o registro da tabela contrato e seus respectivos registros na tabela contato. Só que para alterar o contato, passo o Idcont (chave primária da tabela contrato) mais a informação de data da tabela contato.
Ao clicar em alterar não acontece nada. Nem mensagem de erro nem a alteração. Já revisei todo o código, mudei método de bindParam para bindValue, etc.

Segue o código do formulário de alteração.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cadastro de contrato</title>
</head>

<body>
  <Table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
    <caption align="center" size="20px">
      <font size="5px">Alterar Contato</font>
    </caption>
    <form name="form1" action="altera_cont.php" method="post">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="idcont" id="fixo" size="5" value="<?=$resultado['idcont'] ?>"> Data: <input type="date" name="cdata" id="cdata" size="10" readonly="true" value="<?=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($resultado['cdata'])) ?>">&nbsp; Contato:
          <input
            type="text" name="contato" id="contato" size="50" value="<?=$resultado['contato'] ?>"> &nbsp; Obs.: <input type="text" name="obs" id="obs" size="85" value="<?=$resultado['obs'] ?>">&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" value="Alterar"></td>
      </tr>

    </form>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

A rotina de alteração é essa:

```html
<?php
require_once 'inicia.php';
/** COLETA AS INFORMAÇÕES DIGITADAS NO FORMULÁRIO FORM_ALTERA.PHP **/
$idcont = isset($_POST['idcont']) ? $_POST['idcont'] : null;
$cdata = isset($_POST['cdata']) ? $_POST['cdata'] : null;
$cdata = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($cdata));
$contato = isset($_POST['contato']) ? $_POST['contato'] : null;
$obs = isset($_POST['obs']) ? $_POST['obs'] : null;
/** VERIFICA SE TODOS OS CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO ESTÃO PREENCHIDOS **/
if (empty($contato) || empty($cdata)){
   echo "Os campos Contato, Data, NÃO podem conter valor nulo!";
   exit;
} 
/** ALTERA AS INFORMAÇÕES NA TABELA CONTRATO DO BANCO DE DADOS COMERCIAL **/
$PDO = conecta_bd();
$sql = "UPDATE contato SET cdata=:cdata,contato=:contato,obs=:obs WHERE idcont=:idcont AND cdata=:cdata";
$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':contato', $contato);
$stmt->bindParam(':obs', $obs);
$stmt->bindParam(':idcont', $idcont, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':cdata', $cdata);

if ($stmt->execute()){
   header('Location: contatos.php');
}
else{
   echo "Ocorreu um erro na alteração do contato!";
   print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado para a alteração não ser realizada?

Answer (score 0):

O problema parece ser o fato de do placeholder `cdata` servir para dois propositos (pesquisar e ser o novo valor). A chave primária deveria ser o suficiente para encontrar o registro nesse caso você deve, remover `cdata` do seu where ou criar dois placeholders um para cada finalidade.

Comment: O cdata e icont são a chave primária composta da tabela contato. Estou me inteirando do placeholders e realizando testes. Qualquer coisa posto aqui a dúvida ou a solução. Grato.

Comment: @Jamesfk então use dois, um com o novo valor e outro para pesquisa.

Comment: rray, cdata não necessita ser alterado, seria o ideal. Já realizei testes com ele só no filtro e não funcionou. o placeholder é só um exemplo do que deve ser preenchido pelo usuário, preciso que exiba os valores atuais dos campos e permitir alterar. Já retirei o cdata do update, não resolveu também.